# Trigger flow with icon instead of button?

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, power-automate, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have a SharePoint list with a button that has conditional logic to trigger a flow. It works (conditions display or hide it as needed as well as adjusting color and label as needed), but it doesn't look great.

[image]

I realize that I can do some minor formatting in the button (make the background color less dramatic, for example), but I'm wondering if it's possible to have an email icon that the user could click to trigger the flow, instead of the big button.

Here's my JSON formatting for the field:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "button",
      "txtContent": "=if(([$RequestStatus] == 'Requested Proof'), if(([$LogProofRequested] == ''), 'Click to Send Request Proof Message', 'Click to Re-Send Request Proof Message'), if(([$RequestStatus] == 'Received Proof'), if(([$LogProofReceived] == ''), 'Click to Send Received Proof Message', 'Click to Re-Send Received Proof Message'), if(([$RequestStatus] == 'Cancelled'), if(([$LogCancelled] == ''), 'Click to Send Cancelled Message', 'Click to Re-Send Cancelled Message'), 'No associated message to send')",
      "customRowAction": {
        "action": "executeFlow",
        "actionParams": "=if(([$RequestStatus] == 'Requested Proof'),'{\"id\":\"cea60216-5abe-4170-bd1d-e00c6c7d6ddb\",\"headerText\":\"Request Proof Notification\",\"runFlowButtonText\":\"Send Now\"}',if(([$RequestStatus] == 'Received Proof'), if(([$Period] == 'Next Year'), '{\"id\":\"3c8d3211-2cac-49e7-8767-49e986246a03\",\"headerText\":\"Received Proof Notification\",\"runFlowButtonText\":\"Send Now\"}', '{\"id\":\"2e5281f3-5378-4a35-8e3d-700b74ea56c4\",\"headerText\":\"Received Proof Notification\",\"runFlowButtonText\":\"Send Now\"}'), if(([$RequestStatus] == 'Cancelled'),'{\"id\":\"ca089b5b-ed8e-4e7b-9283-c7a41553e45a\",\"headerText\":\"Cancelled Notification\",\"runFlowButtonText\":\"Send Now\"}','{\"id\":\"b8643251-b284-4089-ba29-d1223a179bc9\"}')))"
      },
      "style": {
        "background-color": "=if(([$RequestStatus] == 'Requested Proof'), if(([$LogProofRequested] == ''), 'green', 'darkblue'), if(([$RequestStatus] == 'Received Proof'), if(([$LogProofReceived] == ''), 'green', 'darkblue'), if(([$RequestStatus] == 'Cancelled'), if(([$LogCancelled] == ''), 'green', 'darkblue'), 'orange')",
        "color": "white",
        "display": "=if([$Period]=='' || [$Recipients]=='', 'none', if([$Period]=='Next Year', if([$RequestStatus]=='Received Proof' && [$ApprovedSchool]!='' && [$PreviouslyDesignatedSchool]!='', 'inherit', if([$RequestStatus] == 'Requested Proof' || [$RequestStatus] == 'Cancelled', 'inherit', 'none')), if([$Period]=='Current Year', if([$RequestStatus]=='Received Proof' && [$ApprovedSchool]!='' && toString([$TransferDate])!='', 'inherit', if([$RequestStatus]=='Requested Proof' || [$RequestStatus]=='Cancelled', 'inherit', 'none')), 'none')))"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "txtContent": "[$NotificationSummary]",
      "style": {
        "display": "=if([$Period]=='' || [$Recipients]=='', 'inherit', if([$Period]=='Next Year', if([$RequestStatus]=='Received Proof' && [$ApprovedSchool]!='' && [$PreviouslyDesignatedSchool]!='', 'none', if([$RequestStatus] == 'Requested Proof' || [$RequestStatus] == 'Cancelled', 'none', 'inherit')), if([$Period]=='Current Year', if([$RequestStatus]=='Received Proof' && [$ApprovedSchool]!='' && toString([$TransferDate])!='', 'none', if([$RequestStatus]=='Requested Proof' || [$RequestStatus]=='Cancelled', 'none', 'inherit')), 'inherit')))"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to use an icon instead of a button, but retain the "action" and "actionParams" and associate them with that icon to launch the flow?

Update: Working Solution

Thanks to Ganesh I was able to get the icon displayed... I wasn't able to get it within the button, but adding the span before the button element still helps, and I removed the border and background color on the button since the icon prompts the user to action. I also added code to change the cursor to a pointer when over the button text.

Here's the new, cleaner look:

[image]

And here's the code to get that result:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "Mail"
      },
      "style": {
        "padding-right": "6px",
        "display": "=if([$Period]=='' || [$Recipients]=='', 'none', if([$Period]=='Next Year', if([$RequestStatus]=='Received Proof' && [$ApprovedSchool]!='' && [$PreviouslyDesignatedSchool]!='', 'inherit', if([$RequestStatus] == 'Requested Proof' || [$RequestStatus] == 'Cancelled', 'inherit', 'none')), if([$Period]=='Current Year', if([$RequestStatus]=='Received Proof' && [$ApprovedSchool]!='' && toString([$TransferDate])!='', 'inherit', if([$RequestStatus]=='Requested Proof' || [$RequestStatus]=='Cancelled', 'inherit', 'none')), 'none')))"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "button",
      "txtContent": "=if(([$RequestStatus] == 'Requested Proof'), if(([$LogProofRequested] == ''), 'Send Request Proof Message', 'Re-Send Request Proof Message'), if(([$RequestStatus] == 'Received Proof'), if(([$LogProofReceived] == ''), 'Send Received Proof Message', 'Re-Send Received Proof Message'), if(([$RequestStatus] == 'Cancelled'), if(([$LogCancelled] == ''), 'Send Cancelled Message', 'Re-Send Cancelled Message'), 'No associated message to send')",
      "customRowAction": {
        "action": "executeFlow",
        "actionParams": "=if(([$RequestStatus] == 'Requested Proof'),'{\"id\":\"cea60216-5abe-4170-bd1d-e00c6c7d6ddb\",\"headerText\":\"Request Proof Notification\",\"runFlowButtonText\":\"Send Now\"}',if(([$RequestStatus] == 'Received Proof'), if(([$Period] == 'Next Year'), '{\"id\":\"3c8d3211-2cac-49e7-8767-49e986246a03\",\"headerText\":\"Received Proof Notification\",\"runFlowButtonText\":\"Send Now\"}', '{\"id\":\"2e5281f3-5378-4a35-8e3d-700b74ea56c4\",\"headerText\":\"Received Proof Notification\",\"runFlowButtonText\":\"Send Now\"}'), if(([$RequestStatus] == 'Cancelled'),'{\"id\":\"ca089b5b-ed8e-4e7b-9283-c7a41553e45a\",\"headerText\":\"Cancelled Notification\",\"runFlowButtonText\":\"Send Now\"}','{\"id\":\"b8643251-b284-4089-ba29-d1223a179bc9\"}')))"
      },
      "style": {
        "font-size": "12px",
        "cursor": "pointer",
        "border": "none",
        "background-color": "white",
        "color": "=if(([$RequestStatus] == 'Requested Proof'), if(([$LogProofRequested] == ''), 'darkgreen', 'darkblue'), if(([$RequestStatus] == 'Received Proof'), if(([$LogProofReceived] == ''), 'green', 'darkblue'), if(([$RequestStatus] == 'Cancelled'), if(([$LogCancelled] == ''), 'green', 'darkblue'), 'orange')",
        "display": "=if([$Period]=='' || [$Recipients]=='', 'none', if([$Period]=='Next Year', if([$RequestStatus]=='Received Proof' && [$ApprovedSchool]!='' && [$PreviouslyDesignatedSchool]!='', 'inherit', if([$RequestStatus] == 'Requested Proof' || [$RequestStatus] == 'Cancelled', 'inherit', 'none')), if([$Period]=='Current Year', if([$RequestStatus]=='Received Proof' && [$ApprovedSchool]!='' && toString([$TransferDate])!='', 'inherit', if([$RequestStatus]=='Requested Proof' || [$RequestStatus]=='Cancelled', 'inherit', 'none')), 'none')))"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "txtContent": "[$NotificationSummary]",
      "style": {
        "display": "=if([$Period]=='' || [$Recipients]=='', 'inherit', if([$Period]=='Next Year', if([$RequestStatus]=='Received Proof' && [$ApprovedSchool]!='' && [$PreviouslyDesignatedSchool]!='', 'none', if([$RequestStatus] == 'Requested Proof' || [$RequestStatus] == 'Cancelled', 'none', 'inherit')), if([$Period]=='Current Year', if([$RequestStatus]=='Received Proof' && [$ApprovedSchool]!='' && toString([$TransferDate])!='', 'none', if([$RequestStatus]=='Requested Proof' || [$RequestStatus]=='Cancelled', 'none', 'inherit')), 'inherit')))"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will require `button` element to use `action` and `actionParams`.

However, you can add children elements to button element to add icon & text (if required).

**Example**:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "button",
  "customRowAction": {
    "action": "executeFlow",
    "actionParams": "{\"id\": \"edf627d9-20f4-45ba-8bc9-4494bf2ff1be\"}"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "class": "ms-fontColor-themePrimary ms-fontColor-themeDarker--hover"
  },
  "style": {
    "border": "none",
    "background-color": "transparent",
    "cursor": "pointer"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "Flow"
      },
      "style": {
        "padding-right": "6px"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "It's Flow Time!"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Reference**: [Create a button to launch a Flow for the selected item](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/column-samples/generic-start-flow)

Comment: Hi @Darryl, did you try this? Is it working for you?

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out where to add the iconName property. I have "children" in my main div, but do I need to add one into my elmType: button section as well? And I have 2 div elmTypes but no span elmType... do I need to add a span into one of my divs? Or replace a div with a span? Sorry - I don't have a CSS background so I'm struggling a bit with this part.

Comment: This is up to you. If you want to show the icon inside button, you have to add children element into button element & the span is used just to add the icon. So, create a span element as a children into button element & set `iconName` inside `attributes` property of span element to the name of icon you want to show.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't get the icon to display when putting the span with the icon inside the button element, but was able to get it to appear before the button (almost as good - the only drawback is I need to have my "display" condition run once for the button and once for the icon, and the icon isn't clickable, but it's still a big improvement.